# How to select latest 4 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to write a query to select last 4 dates from the table for each person. I know that i can use max(date) to select the most recent date but how to select last 4 dates starting from starting from the most recent one for each person.

What I tried was (as below) but this only gives me most recent date of event.

```
select user, max(date)  
from users  
group by user
```

The result i would like to see is:

user | date
John | 30/03/2017
John | 27/03/2017
John | 21/02/2017
John | 04/01/2017
Andy | 29/03/2017
Andy | 27/02/2017
Andy | 21/02/2017
Andy | 01/01/2017

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code-writing service. Also: You haven't shown *any* data - should people just imagine what your tables look like?

Comment: did you try my solution below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shot in the dark:

```
select t.person, o.date
from table t
outer apply (
select top 4 t2.date 
from table2 t2
where t.personID = t2.personID
Order by t2.date desc
) o
```

Comment: Give us a simple example of what your starting table and what you want your output table to look like.

My first guess was this:
Name Date
Rob Jan 1
Rob Jan 2
Rob Jan 3
Rob Jan 4

Comment: Don't place clarification questions/comments under your answer - they belong under the question. And I already requested that *exact same info* in my comment under the question. Along with the point that, without showing any code or data, the question is un-answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ROW_NUMBER function:

```
 WITH cte
 AS
 (
 SELECT user, date, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date DESC) row
 FROM users
 )

 SELECT user, date
 FROM cte
 WHERE row <= 4
```

However if a user can have duplicate dates, you are be better of using DENSE_RANK and add a DISTINCT after SELECT:

```
DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date DESC) row
```